# uniform limit of step function

Tags: real-analysis

Define a step function to be a function that is piecewise constant, $$
f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i\chi_{[a_i,b_i)},$$ where $[a_i,b_i)$ are disjoint intervals.

1. Prove that every continuous function on a compact interval is a uniform limit of step functions.
2. Prove that a uniform limit of step functions (on a compact 
   interval) is Riemann integrable.

For second one, if 1. holds, uniform convergence can be used to establish integrability and dif­ferentiability of limits of functions and the interchange of the operation and the limit. So, if $f_n$ are Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is Riemann integrable and
$$
\int_a^bf_ndx\longrightarrow\int_a^bfdx.
$$
But, how can I prove the first lemma?

Comment: Hint: such an $f$ is uniformly continuous on the given interval.

Answer (score 3):

Some authors called such a function $f : I\subseteq\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ admissible, i.e. if it is the uniform limit of step functions.

1. Let $\varepsilon=\dfrac{1}{n},$ $n\in\mathbb{N^*}$. For $\varepsilon$ we determine a $\delta>0$ such that
   for all $x,y\in\left[a,b\right] $ with
   $$
   \left\vert x-y\right\vert <\delta,
   $$
   we have
   $$
   \left\vert f\left(  x\right)  -f\left(  y\right)  \right\vert <\varepsilon.
   $$
   Let $m$ m the greatest integer with
   $$
   \delta<\dfrac{b-a}{m}\text{ or }a+m\delta<b.
   $$
   For every integer $l$ with $0\leq l\leq m$ we set
   $$
   x_{l}:=a+l\delta\text{ and }x_{m+1}:=b
   $$
   and define a step function by
   $$
   f_{n}\left(  x\right)  =\left\{
   \begin{array}
   [c]{l}%
   f\left(  x_{l}\right)  ,\text{ for }x_{l}\leq x<x_{l+1}\\
   f\left(  b\right)  ,\text{ for }x=b
   \end{array}
   .\right.
   $$
   Then for all $x\in\left[a,b\right]  $ we have
   \begin{align*}
   \left\vert f\left(  x\right)  -f_{n}\left(  x\right)  \right\vert  &
   =\left\vert f\left(  x\right)  -f\left(  x_{l}\right)  \right\vert \\
   & <\dfrac{1}{n},
   \end{align*}
   as $\left\vert x-x_{l}\right\vert <\delta$ .
   Finally, $\left(  f_{n}\right)  _{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to  $f$
2. You are right.